# webpack-dev-server --inline recompiles and reloads page but no changes shown

Tags: javascript, php, webpack

I'm having some issues getting Webpack's live reloading working. I believe I have everything setup correctly. The problem is when saving files the browser refreshes but no changes are displayed.

I run the webpack development server with the following command:

```
webpack-dev-server --inline
```

And I start my PHP development server with this command:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

In my `public/index.php` file include the `webpack-dev-server.js` file:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
```

When I make a changes to `entry.js` and hit save I can see the files recompiling and the browser refreshes. Except no changes are made.

I get the following output at the terminal when saving `entry.js`:

```
Time: 44ms
  Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
 app.js   240 kB       0  [emitted]  main
app.css  42.4 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} app.js, app.css (main) 222 kB [rendered]
   [75] ./src/js/entry.js 108 bytes {0} [built]
     + 77 hidden modules
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
webpack: bundle is now INVALID.
Hash: 3937d6fc90a1794a8daa
Version: webpack 1.13.3
```

I tried to add a simple `alert("Testing");` to `entry.js` but got no popup. If I check the `webpack-dev-server.js` file for any line that contains the word `Testing` it finds non.

Here is the contents of `webpack.config.js`:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/js/entry.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: "app.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  },
  postcss: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('precss'),
    require('postcss-custom-media'),
    require('lost')
  ],
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css')
  ]
};
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** Also tried the following:

`php -S localhost:8000 -t public` starts the webserver. `webpack-dev-server --content-base=public --inline --hot --watch"` starts the webpack-dev-server. I load `localhost:8000/index.php` and monitor the console inspector. I can see that hot module replacement is enabled. If I modify and save `entry.js` and include a simple `alert('Hello');` I can see in the web console that it's recompiling. The page refreshes, yet nothing happens. No changes to be seen.

Comment: Could this be an issue with the publicPath that is set, either in the webpack config or what you are passing to the webpack-dev-server?

Comment: @JoeBruno I don't have publicPath set in the webpack config. The only path I have set is `--content-base`.